# Is there a way for tailwind.config.js to auto bundle dynamic class attributes on leptos

Tags: tailwind-css, leptos

so I was trying out tailwindcss with leptos framework, what I noticed is when classes are included in static class attribute, the tailwindcss config recognize and build up those in output.css. however if I was to include class name using Dynamic Classes in leptos framework, those classes are not being auto included in output.css. Eg. 'rounded-lg' style won't be included in output.css

```
use leptos::*;
use leptos_meta::*;

#[component]
fn App(cx: Scope) -> impl IntoView {
    let (count, set_count) = create_signal(cx, 0);
    provide_meta_context(cx);

    view! { cx,
        <Stylesheet id="leptos" href="/pkg/tailwind.css"/>
        <button
            class="p-1 px-2.5 bg-sky-500 hover:bg-sky-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-sky-300 hover:text-white"
            class:rounded-lg=move || count() % 2 == 1
            on:click=move |_| {
                set_count.update(|n| *n += 1);
            }
        >
        "Click me: " {move || count()}
        </button>
    }
}

fn main() {
    leptos::mount_to_body(|cx| view!{ cx, <App/> })
}
```

I had to manually add those styles to output.css, wondering if there is better way to auto extract that rather than adding it manually all the time.

Comment: by dynamic you mean runtime defined css classes? It does not work with tailwind. There are workarounds but tailwind is not built for runtime. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Otherwise could you elaborate what the line "class:rounded-lg=move || count() % 2 ==" actually does?

Comment: ya, that's what I meant, runtime defined classes

Comment: If you add spaces around `rounded-lg` will be that valid syntax for leptos? eg `class: rounded-lg =move || count() % 2 == 1`

Comment: interesting.. spacing did the trick.. if i have a space after the colon, it picked up that class.. strange.. hmm thanx, wish i could vote u up .. yikes !! :)
also do u know why adding a number it complains its a invalid tag.. example if i add rounded-2xl then leptos complain its a invalid tag name or attribute key

Comment: @FerinPatel The problem here is [exctraction](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#customizing-extraction-logic) logic - Tailwind reads code as text and extract its utilities according to regex - every word divided by quotes, spaces, some other symbols. In your case it considers `class:rounded-lg=move` as one utility. You need to customize extraction logic to a new regex which should include both `:` and `=` signs. This will break variants so you need to change [separator](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#separator) too. Or just add spaces around utility to match regex

Comment: @FerinPatel don't know why leptos (this is not my stack) considers its invalid tag - I guess it has numbers in it. I would recommend not to use Tailwind utilities in dynamic classes - Tailwind may have a lot of "not allowed symbols" (`/` in labels, `[]` in dynamic utilites, numbers etc) you may have to change and it will bring more pain than solve problems. Use [layers](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply) or don't use Tailwind and leptos together. Had similar issue once with Pug and I'm not using them together since

Comment: thanx.. ya layers approach seem viable option.. its just a experimental project as I'm learning leptos.. leptos is new framework and seems promising, however it doesn't yet support any css out of the box. It just happens that tailwinds utility first approach fits well with this framework rather than anything else when it comes to styling components. But thanx for your advice makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

Leptos also supports a tuple-based syntax for dynamic classes, and this works with the default Tailwind parser:

`class=("rounded-lg", move || count() % 2 == 1)`

That said, you can make the other syntax work as well. If you add a space after `class:`, Tailwind will find the dynamic class names, and Leptos will continue to compile successfully.

That is to say, turn this:

`class:rounded-lg=move || count() % 2 == 1`

Into this:

`class: rounded-lg=move || count() % 2 == 1`

Or this:

`class: rounded-lg = move || count() % 2 == 1`

It's also possible to customize the Tailwind parsing for Rust files. The following example tailwind.config.js configures Tailwind to successfully parse the tailwind classes from `class="p-1 bg-sky-500"` and `class:rounded-lg=move || count() % 2 == 1` and `class=("rounded-lg", move || count() % 2 == 1)` in Rust files.

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: {
    files: ["*.html", "./src/**/*.rs"],
    extract: {
      // Support for leptos class:classname=predicate and 
      // class=("classname", predicate) syntax.
      // Without this the tuple syntax works but not 
      // the inline syntax.
      rs: (content) => content
        .match(/(?<=class[:=]\(?"?)[-\w: ]+/g)
        ?.flatMap(s => s.split(' ')) ?? []
    }
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This is a much more thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Safelisting classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes)  `tailwind.config.js` option.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    'rounded-lg'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // ...
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

###### Check out this example I created here with that config setting. https://play.tailwindcss.com/Bpz8xH6Edk?file=config

Even though there is no `HTML` being output, the `rounded-lg` class still gets included into the compiled `CSS`.

[image: Tailwind Play example of Safelisting classes.]

There is another option which is shown under [Working with third party libraries](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#working-with-third-party-libraries).

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;

.c-rounded-lg {
  @apply rounded-lg;
}

/* ... */

@tailwind utilities;
```

> This will ensure that Tailwind always includes those styles in your `CSS`, which is a lot easier than configuring Tailwind to scan the source code of a third-party library.
>
> We recommend writing those styles without using Tailwind’s `@layer` feature

Comment: i guess prolly i didn't explain it right or my question is misleading. leptos framework allows to add dynamic class, i believe trunk bundles up everything on compilation. so not sure if tailwind is responsible to make bundle.css output file or some other tooling.. but its not picking up tailwind classes that are defined as leptos dynamic class

Comment: Sure understandable, that is also why I included the Working with third party libraries bit as Leptos is technically a third party working with Tailwind. Seems you have a working solution for your class though, which is great news.